# Extracting messy JSON values in PrestoDB

Tags: sql, presto

I have an json column in a PrestoDB table `mytable`.  The rows contain **varying amounts** of key-value pairs - sometimes keys are present, and sometimes keys are absent, and sometimes the JSON contained in the row is wrapped in quotes, and sometimes it is not:

```
SELECT mycolumm from mytable 
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 3


{u'foo': 123,  u'bar': u'abc', u'baz': 456}
{u'bar': u'abc'}
"{u'baz': 456}"
```

My objective is to get only the values of rows that contain the key `baz`
However, the following method does not work:

```
SELECT
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(mycolumn, '$["baz"]')
from mytable
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(mycolumn, '$["baz"]') IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id
DESC
```

It should return

```
456
456
```

But the query returns nothing.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your syntax is incorrect. Try this:

```
   select
   JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(mycolumn, '$.baz')
   from mytable
   WHERE JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(mycolumn, '$.baz') IS NOT NULL
   ORDER BY ID DESC
```

You can see how json_path works here: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#path-examples. This is the notation that presto uses to navigate json strings.

Comment: For example the `$..*` gives me errors (invalid json path), at least when used through Amazon Athena.